# “Government by [two/three/many persons]” is to “[diarchy/triarchy/polyarchy]” as “government by simple majority” is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

The government by ...

- ... two persons is called "[diarchy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diarchy#English),"
- ... three persons is called "[triarchy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triarchy),"
- ... many persons is called "[polyarchy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyarchy)."

So, my question is, is there a word to define the government by the simple majority of persons?

More precisely, I'm thinking of a word that completes the following progression:

> diarchy,  triarchy, polyarchy, **X**.

In fact, I think that "polyarchy" doesn't necessarily imply that the number of persons involved in the government is greater than the 50% of the total number of persons involved.<sup><sub><sup>[I hope that this sentence is clearly comprehensible]</sup></sub></sup>

It's worth noting that "democracy" is not the word I'm looking for because such a word, as far as I know, defines a complex concept not based only on the majority criterion.

<sub>**Note**

I have already asked this question on English Language Learners [[→](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/573/government-by-two-persons-is-to-diarchy-as-government-by-simple-majority-i)], but, just after having asked, the question was closed as off topic apparently because it was "*not really a Learners' level of question*." Yet, I think the StoneyB's and Mistu4u's answers aren't entirely satisfactory.</sub>

Comment: I think you may be ascribing a more specific meaning to the word *democracy* than is justified. In common parlance, if a family of five are arguing about which TV channel to watch, all native speakers would understand that if they opt for a *democratic* solution, that would mean *watch whatever the **majority** want*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Majority government*, as other answers have pointed, is the usual phrasing.

If you're necessarily looking for a single word,  [**Arithmocracy**](http://phrontistery.info/govern.html) refers to *government by the simple majority*. Looking it up, [several online dictionaries agree](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=arithmocracy++meaning&oq=arithmocracy++meaning&gs_l=hp.3...568514.570072.4.570578.8.8.0.0.0.0.304.1935.2-7j1.8.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.6J0xz0c0xZI&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.bmk&fp=e4b9e1d505f544c2&biw=1680&bih=886) with the definition.

Comment: Dictionaries do not agree. They agree that *arithmocracy* has to do with numerical supremacy, but not about what that is. Dictionary.com: “rule by the numerical majority of the population”. TheFreeDictionary.com: “rule by that *group* which holds the numerical majority in a state”. Phrontistery.info: “government by *simple majority* ”. Outside North America “simple majority” is commonly used to mean “plurality”. So *arithmocracy* applies variously to majority rule by population, majority rule of those voting, plurality rule by population membership, plurality rule by votes cast, etc.

Comment: @MετάEd : Yes, I did get that sense of *rule by majority,* as opposed to rule by *the group representing the majority.* However, it seems impractical to presume that *arithmocracy* means 51% of the country's population will congregate at one place to sign a bill into law! Ground realities and established democratic practices would grant us that the *group representing the simple numerical majority* is what is being referenced.

Answer (score 3):

There is a cluster of words that come close.

[Oligarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligarchy) is a rule by a few.

[Majority rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_rule) is a form of government based on a majority. The phrase will generally be applied to representative bodies such as parliaments rather than to systems of government.

[Plebiscite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plebiscite) is when the voters of a state vote on a ruler or a matter of opinion. It often requires a majority of voters to pass. It is closely related to...

A [Binding Referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plebiscite) is a vote that will be adopted as law under certain circumstances. It is also a form of *direct democracy*. (You are correct that *democracy*, by itself, is often more complex than a simple majority of voters.)

A [Tyranny of the majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority) captures the worst of government by a simple majority, and I leave it in this cluster because I do not know how you intend to use it.

I hope that one of these might meet your needs.

Comment: +1 for "majority rule", but it is a pity that this definition doesn't have the "sound" I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually referred to simply as a **majority government**, and it's extremely uncommon for a government to have 100% control (if so, it's probably a *dictatorship* rather than *democracy*).

This is opposed to a *minority government*, where the ruling party does not have a majority and is under threat of losing in parliament, making it unstable. Often in these cases, parties will make deals and form a *coalition* so they can rule as a *majority government*.

Answer (score 0):

A government by majority would be a subset of polyarchy (government by many persons).  I think the word you're looking for doesn't exist, any more than there's a specific *single* word for "Diarchy where one of the people is an old man".

Answer (score 0):

If by "simple majority of persons" you mean "simple majority of the persons governed", then that would be *direct democracy* (as opposed to various forms of representative democracy, as an example of democracy that is not direct democracy).